# python - make a service continuosly return a status code without breaking a while loop

Tags: face-recognition, imutils

EDIT: I couldn't find a solution as I wanted below, so I did it as a simple write and read into a .txt file since both apps are in the same physical server. I'm not closing this because I believe it's still something people might need a real solution. Thanks.

Firstly I'm sorry because I'm not sure how this is called so it's been hard to google search it. A synopsis of my problem is this:

I'm using ageitgey's facial_recognition python library to recognize faces in a video. [Refer to this code](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_webcam_faster.py). So, you see it uses opencv to capture every frame inside a `while True:` and `ret, frame =  video_capture.read()` for the frame.

For every iteration I'll fill a variable (let's name it `RETURN_CODE`) to **0** if no faces are inside the frame, **1** if the face is not recognized and **2** if the face is recognized.

**What I need** is that for every iteration I return this code without breaking the loop so that another application keeps checking this status and do other things based on it's value.

**I'm still figuring out how to flask this, but this is not part of this question.**

Currently I'm printing the output and I read that I might get it using another script with stdout, but it seems wrong to flood the console.
Writing into a file might crash if app1 tries to write while app2 has it opened.

Here is my sample code, modified version from the above link:
notes: for it not crash it has to add 2 images at the same directory as the script, "obama.jpg" and "biden.jpg" from this repo: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/tree/master/examples

```
import face_recognition
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

import time

# our variable
RETURN_CODE = 0



# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    obama_face_encoding,
    biden_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "Barack Obama",
    "Joe Biden"
]

# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

# start capturing frame by frame
## changed for imutils as is much better and opencv crashes a lot
video_capture = VideoStream(src=0).start()
TEST_START = time.time()
while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    frame = video_capture.read()

    # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)

    # THis will resize the frame on screen
    r = frame.shape[1] / float(small_frame.shape[1])

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)



        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
            # if True in matches:
            #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
            #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
            face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
            if matches[best_match_index]:
                name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

        if name == 'Unkown':
            RETURN_CODE = 1
        else:
            RETURN_CODE = 2

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


    # Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top = int(top * r)
        right = int(right * r)
        bottom = int(bottom * r)
        left = int(left * r)

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    #Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # Currently it's printing the code, later add into a flask
    print(RETURN_CODE)
    #yield RETURN_CODE


    if time.time() - TEST_START >= 10.0:
        break
# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.stream.release()
video_capture.stop()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you are searching for inter-process communication. The return code is just what a program returns when it exits.

Writing to a file like you said is one way to do it but there are (many) others.

For example take a look at the Python pipes and queues: 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#pipes-and-queues

Another more general approach is to run a queue service like Redis: https://python-rq.org/

Comment: Hello, thanks for you reply. I'm not enterely sure how this would be implemented or if it fits me. A side note is that my `RETURN_CODE` is a custom number and should not be taken as other codes as such `HTTPs`. How should I apply this at my code above (app1) and how should app2 get that code?